# grails.util.Metadata.getServletVersion throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: grails

Calling `Holders.grailsApplication.metadata.getServletVersion()` throws the following error wherever I place the code:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
        at java.util.Optional.<init>(Optional.java:96)
        at java.util.Optional.of(Optional.java:108)
        at grails.util.Metadata.getServletVersion(Metadata.groovy:284)
        at grails.util.Metadata$getServletVersion$1.call(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: FYI... there are not many good reasons to ever invoke `Holders.grailsApplication.metadata.getServletVersion()`.  There are better ways to get that value.  Can you summarize from what context you are invoking that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Add the following to `application.yml`:

```yaml
info:
    app:
        servletVersion: '3.0'
```

---

##### Or set through the command line:

```bash
./gradlew bootRun -Dinfo.app.servletVersion=3.0
```

Having the following in your `bootRun` block in `build.gradle`:

```java
bootRun {
    systemProperties(System.getProperties())
}
```

Comment: In both of these cases, you're just explicitly setting a property to a value.  Is that what you wanted, or were you trying to access something specified within the framework?

Comment: Yes, actually. Someone asked me why he was having this error. I just wanted to catalog a solution.